# No "--version" switch for tsc on Ubuntu

Tags: version, typescript, tsc

How do you find out which version of typescript/tsc you run under Ubuntu? There's no manual or `--version` switch for `tsc`.

Comment: `--version` works fine for me.

Comment: @false Strange. Do you know how I can remove tsc to reinstall it?

Comment: That depends on how you installed it in the first place. `npm install -g`? `npm uninstall -g typescript` should work. (I think just running `install` again will upgrade it, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Since I use Ubuntu 12.04, I installed an older version of node without my knowing, which in turn installed an older version of typescript. Appareantly, the old tsc command does not have the --version switch, but the new one has.

Answer (score 0):

In any version of TypeScript if you type in `tsc` without any arguments it shows you its version in the help message.